# Show Near by location using og:latitude and og:longtitide meta tags

Tags: iphone, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add the following two meta tags ro the webpage I am going to share,

```
<meta property="og:latitude" content="37.416343"/> <meta property="og:longitude" content="-122.153013"/>
```

The purpose is to utilize the location data I have in my server in the facebook post.
So When a  user shares a link from my mobile app , the webpage directed by the link will include this meta data information. However I can't see any location info on my posts.

What I am missing here ?

I have verified the namespaces and tried by changing "og:type" to "cafe"  as well.